# style.display and href value = #

Tags: jquery, iframe, dhtml

I have the following problem.

I have a page that adds iFrames dynamically using jQuery.

Inside of the content of some iFrames there are hyperlinks like:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="hideTestDiv();">
```

the function hideTestDiv does:

...

```
document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
```

..

in IEs browsers, this causes the main page to scroll right to top and the first element of the main page disappears.

I dont know how to fix this because i can't modify the content of the iFrames.

I really appreciate any help.

The next is a example to reproduce the bug.

The main page:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">


    <title>Dynamic tabs with jQuery - why and how to create them | JankoAtWarpSpeed Demos</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        body { font-family:Lucida Sans, Lucida Sans Unicode, Arial, Sans-Serif; font-size:13px; margin:0px auto;}
        #tabs { margin:0; padding:0; list-style:none; overflow:hidden; }
        #tabs li { float:left; display:block; padding:5px; background-color:#bbb; margin-right:5px;}
        #tabs li a { color:#fff; text-decoration:none; }
        #tabs li.current { background-color:#e1e1e1;}
        #tabs li.current a { color:#000; text-decoration:none; }
        #tabs li a.remove { color:#f00; margin-left:10px;}
        #content { width:100%; height:100%; background-color:#e1e1e1;}


        #main { width:900px;  height:100%; margin:0px auto; overflow:hidden;background-color:#F6F6F6; margin-top:0px;
             -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:0px;}
        #wrapper, #doclist { float:left; margin:0 20px 0 0;}
        #doclist { width:70px; border-right:solid 1px #dcdcdc;}
        #doclist ul { margin:0; list-style:none;}
        #doclist li { margin:10px 0; padding:0;}
        #documents { margin:0; padding:0;}

        #wrapper { width:100%; height:500px; margin-top:0px;}

        #header{ background-color:#F6F6F6; width:900px; margin:0px auto; margin-top:0px;
             -moz-border-radius:10px;  -webkit-border-radius:10px; padding:30px; position:relative;}
        #header h2 {font-size:16px; font-weight:normal; margin:0px; padding:0px;}

    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="Dynamic%20tabs%20with%20jQuery%20_archivos/jquery-1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#documents a").click(function() {
                addTab($(this));
            });



            $('#tabs a.tab').live('click', function() {
                // Get the tab name
                var contentname = $(this).attr("id") + "_content";

                // hide all other tabs
                $("#content iframe").hide();
                $("#tabs li").removeClass("current");

                // show current tab
                $("#" + contentname).show();
                $(this).parent().addClass("current");
            });

            $('#tabs a.remove').live('click', function() {
                // Get the tab name
                var tabid = $(this).parent().find(".tab").attr("id");

                // remove tab and related content
                var contentname = tabid + "_content";
                $("#" + contentname).remove();
                $(this).parent().remove();

                // if there is no current tab and if there are still tabs left, show the first one
                if ($("#tabs li.current").length == 0 && $("#tabs li").length > 0) {

                    // find the first tab    
                    var firsttab = $("#tabs li:first-child");
                    firsttab.addClass("current");

                    // get its link name and show related content
                    var firsttabid = $(firsttab).find("a.tab").attr("id");
                    $("#" + firsttabid + "_content").show();
                }
            });
        });
        function addTab(link) {
            // If tab already exist in the list, return
            if ($("#" + $(link).attr("rel")).length != 0)
                return;

            // hide other tabs
            $("#tabs li").removeClass("current");
            $("#content iframe").hide();

            // add new tab and related content
            $("#tabs").append("<li class='current'><a class='tab' id='" +
                $(link).attr("rel") + "' href='#'>" + $(link).html() + 
                "</a><a href='#' class='remove'>x</a></li>");

   $("#content").append("<iframe width='100%' height='100%'  frameborder='0' id='" + $(link).attr("rel") + "_content' src='"+ 
                $(link).attr("title") + "'/>");

            // set the newly added tab as current
            $("#" + $(link).attr("rel") + "_content").show();
        }
    </script>
</head><body bgcolor="#F8F7F6">

    <div id="main">
 <div id="dummy">
 should not dissapear
 </div >
    <div id="doclist">

        <ul id="documents">
            <li><a href="#" rel="Servicio1" title="tab_content.html">service 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Servicio2" title="http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/">service 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Servicio3" title="http://www.facebook.com/">service 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="Servicio4" title="http://www.save-ass.com/code/2010/01/28/pestanas-dinamicas-con-jquery/">service 4</a></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <ul id="tabs">
            <!-- Tabs go here -->
        </ul>
        <div id="content">
            <!-- Tab content goes here -->
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</body></html>
```

the iframe with url=# (tab_content.html)

```
<html>

 <head>
  <title>JavaScript Popup Example 3</title>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Dynamic%20tabs%20with%20jQuery%20_archivos/jquery-1.js"></script>
  <script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

  function hideTestDiv() {
  document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'none';
  }

  function showTestDiv() {
   document.getElementById('test').style.display = 'block';
  }

 </script> 

</head>

<body >

    <a href="#" onclick="hideTestDiv();">             hide test div  </a>
    <br> 
    <a href="#" onclick="showTestDiv();">               show test div     </a>
  <br>

<div id="test"> some content to hide or show</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `return false;` after the `hideTestDiv();` -- that prevents the click event from happening and the href from being called.

Answer (score 1):

You need to return false after your call to hideTestDiv function like so:

`<a href="#" onclick="hideTestDiv(); return false;">`

otherwise after your onClick javascript is executed the link is followed (a link to # is a link to the current page - some browsers will jump back to the top of the page when you follow such a link)

Comment: That won't work unless you also return the function's value to the event, as in `onlick="return hideTestDiv();"`.

Comment: Doh, you're right! That'll teach me to do too many things at once! I've edited my answer to do it the simpler way :-)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for yours answers.

I have resolved this issue:

In the javascript function called addTab, after the next line:

```
$("#" + $(link).attr("rel") + "_content").show();
```

I added the folloging code:

```
$("#" + $(link).attr("rel") + "_content").load(
            function(){
              $("#" + $(link).attr("rel") + "_content")
              .contents().find('a[href=#]')
              .bind('click',function (event) { event.preventDefault();});
            }
            );
```

I had to do that because in the real case, I don't have permissions to add code directly in the content of the iframes.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to intercept the click event on the iframe and stop it from affecting the parent frame with something like this:

```
            $("#content iframe").live('click', function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();
            });
```

That will also prevent clicks in the iframes from affecting the parent via something like:

```
<a href="malicioussite.com?s=innocentsite.com" target="_top">InnocentSite.com</a>
```

Or something like:

```
<a href="#top">Top</a>
```

Anyway, whatever works, right?